# electron : display basic notification in a Tray application

Tags: javascript, electron, tray

I am making a tray application and I try to display a basic notification :

My main.js file and package.json are bellow :

my app/main.js file

```
 const path = require('path');
    const {
        app,
        globalShortcut,
        Tray,
        Notification
    } = require('electron');

    app.on('ready', () => {
        tray = new Tray(path.join(__dirname, 'icon-light.png'));

        globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Shift+N', () => {
            console.log("Roger");
            let myNotification = new Notification('Title', {
                body: 'Rabbit'
            })

            myNotification.onclick = () => {
                console.log('Notification clicked')
            }
        });
    })
```

my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "test_notification",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

When I trigger the keystroke CommandOrControl+Shift+N , it displays me the console.log but not the notification.

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you have missed `new` in the following code.

```
let myNotification = new Notification('Title', {
                body: 'Rabbit'
            })
```

Reference: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/notifications

Comment: oups sorry you are right, but It's just a forgetfulness on my part. It does not work even with new, I will fix my question

Answer (score 0):

Notifications sent from the main process don't use the [HTML5 Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Notification) but make use instead of the [Notification](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/notification) module; that is why the provided code does correctly obtain the `Notification` constructor by destructuring the result of `require('electron')`:

```
const {
    app,
    globalShortcut,
    Tray,
    Notification
} = require('electron');
```

But the interface is slightly different:

- The [constructor](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/notification#new-notificationoptions-experimental) takes only one `options` argument, which includes the `title`:

  ```
  let myNotification = new Notification({
      title: 'Title',
      body: 'Rabbit'
  });
  ```
- The notification must then be explicitly shown using [notification.show()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/notification#notificationshow):

  ```
  myNotification.show();
  ```

> notification.show()
>
> Immediately shows the notification to the user, please note this means
>   unlike the HTML5 Notification implementation, instantiating a
>   `new Notification` does not immediately show it to the user, you need
>   to call this method before the OS will display it.

Comment: it looks good but when I write  let myNotification = new Notification({
            title: 'Title',
            body: 'Rabbit'
        });

        myNotification.onclick = () => {
            console.log('Notification clicked')
        }

        myNotification.show();  then,  no notification id displayed

Comment: Since the main process doesn't use the HTML5 API, there is no `onclick` handler either... Please refer to the Electron documentation, specifically to the [Instance Events](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/notification#instance-events) section. This should work: `myNotification.show(); myNotification.on('click', () => { console.log('Notification clicked'); });` in this very order, or not...

Comment: thank you for your answere but wathever the on click event, no notication is shown at all

Comment: It may depend on the platform or some system setting, I don't know. You may want to try to install this simple [Test Tray Menu](https://github.com/Mikaeru69/test-tray-menu) application and have a look at its source code, it works for me on macOS, Linux Mint and Ubuntu; it doesn't implement a global keyboard shortcut though.